# Android - Emulator internet access on iMac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, keyboard-shortcuts

F8 or Fn + F8 won't work on iMac to toggle internet connection on the emulator.
`/sdk/tools/emulator -help-keys`  say F8 can be used for the same.

Fn + F8 opens the iTunes application when `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` has been selected on `System Pref -> Keyboard`

Anyone facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling this keyboard setting in Mac OS X preferences?

```
[ ] Use all F1, F2, etc. key as standard function keys
```

What about enabling OS X's on-screen keyboard and using that?

Comment: I tried enabling `'Use all F1, F2 ....'` setting without any success. I created a new AVD with `target = Android 2.1-update1`, `SD size = 16 MiB` and `Skin Built-in = HVGA`. This setup worked. 

Problem was on previous AVD that had `target = Android 2.2`, and `Skin Built-in = WVGA800`